# How to grep + show only the 7 most recently modified files?

Tags: debian, grep, wildcards

I want to search the following by `grep` + show the seven most recently modified files. I can list those files by `ls -1t  | head -n 7`. 
Code which order alphabetically as default

```
grep -i "root" *.tex
```

OS: Debian 8.7

Comment: What do you mean by "Code but without custom order"?  You have already answered your own question.  `grep -i "root" $(ls -t *.tex | head -n7)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zsh`:

```
grep -i -- root *.tex(.om[1,7])
```

- `(.om[1,7])`: [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers)
- `.`: regular files only
- `om`: order by last modification time (youngest first like in `ls -t`)
- `[1,7]` only first to seventh ones.

If you also want to consider symlinks to `tex` files (and consider the mtime of the file at the end of the symlink chain), add a `-` glob qualifier before the `.` which tells zsh that the following glob qualifiers apply to the target of the symlinks. If you also want to consider hidden `tex` files, add the `D` glob qualifier.

Comment: What is the syntax `(om[begin,end])`? How does `om` come?

Comment: Great! How did you find the list of these glob qualifiers in Zsh manual? - - Adding `D` like `grep -i root *.tex(om[1,7]D)`?

Comment: @Léo, see link. In `info zsh` (you may need to install the `zsh-doc` package), bring the index with `i` and type `qualif<Tab>`